# Navision How to Convert a Text to Option

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav

I have a text variable which I want to convert into a option and set table data with it. How do it convert the variable into a option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,

```
    OptionName := OptionName::Option;
```

This does not solve the question itself, but is a workaround since "Option" can be a text String (But it must be a predefined one);

Comment: Yup, Option variables are just enums (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type). Don't forget the quotes around option values with spaces in them :)

Answer (score 6):

Should you still wish to convert a string to an option value, EVALUATE is the way to go! :)

Comment: For newbie: Evaluate(Item."Costing Method",TextSample )

Answer (score 0):

```
// Option to text:

optionName := format(salesHeader."Document Type"::Order);


// Text to option:

case (optionName) of
  'Order': salesHeader."Document Type" := salesHeader."Document Type"::Order;
  'Invoice': salesHeader."Document Type" := salesHeader."Document Type"::Invoice;
end;
```